# Trace Ruby calls to "optimized" method calls with TracePoint

Tags: ruby

I am trying to trace all method calls in a Ruby program using TracePoint. It works well until I hit a method call to an "optimized" method call.

Ruby has operators that are "optimized" by replacing YARV instructions with specialized instructions to speed up method calls like greater than, less than. One of these optimized

You can see this using ruby directly by running

```
code = <<END
   1 / 1
END
puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile(code).disasm

# == disasm: <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:<compiled>@<compiled>>==========
# 0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
# 0002 putobject_OP_INT2FIX_O_1_C_
# 0003 putobject_OP_INT2FIX_O_1_C_
# 0004 opt_div          <callinfo!mid:/, argc:1, ARGS_SIMPLE>
# 0006 leave
```

Here you see `opt_div` is used rather than `opt_send_without_block`.

It appears you cannot trace these optimized method calls. For example:

```
trace = TracePoint.trace(:call, :c_call) do |tp|
  tp.disable
  puts "calling #{tp.defined_class}##{tp.method_id}"
  tp.enable
end

trace.enable
1.div(1)
1 / 1
1.div(2)
```

You can see that `1.div` is traced, but not `1/1`

```
calling TracePoint#enable
calling Fixnum#div
calling Fixnum#div
```

So my question is this: How can I trace all method calls including "optimized" method calls in Ruby (MRI)?

Answer (score 1):

From koichi, you can disable the optimizations using:

```
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_option = { specialized_instruction: false }
```

This will work for my cases, but I imagine that it will slow down execution.

One other caveat if you are trying this at home, is that you cannot set that `compile_option` in the same file since by the time it is executed the file is already compiled. Instead you need need to execute this code before loading or requiring the file you are trying to trace.

You can also use this option in eval-d code:

```
iseq = RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile(<<EOS, nil, nil, 1, specialized_instruction: false)
   1 / 1
EOS

trace = TracePoint.trace(:call, :c_call) do |tp|
  tp.disable
  puts "calling #{tp.defined_class}##{tp.method_id}"
  tp.enable
end

iseq.eval
```